# nav component becomes unresponsive on loading new Component

Tags: angular

I am facing a weird issue with my Angular application. When I load a new component, `SignupComponent`, my other component `NavComponent` becomes non-responsive. At application load up, I can enter data in `username` and `password` fields in the login form in `nav` component. But if I click the `signup` link (also in the nav component and it loads the `SignupComponent`), the login form and the links in `nav` becomes unresponsive (I don't even get the hand cursor on hovering over the links). I am no longer able to enter data in `username` and `password` fields.

My SPA is divided into 3 sections, `nav`, `content` and `footer`. The content area will be loaded with new components depending on which menu option is selected in the nav component. `nav` and `footer` areas are suppose to be always visible. The `content` area is dynamic.

app.component.html

```
<div class="css-grid-container">
    <app-nav-component></app-nav-component>
    <app-content-component></app-content-component> <!--this component has router-outlet to put new componnents in it -->
    <app-footer-component></app-footer-component>
  </div>
```

The `app-content-component` has router-link which I use to load new components

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Routes file is

```
const routes:Routes = [
  {
    path: 'signup',
    component: SignupComponentComponent //this components gets loaded in router-link of ContentComponent when signup form in nav component is clicked
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch:'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component:HomepageContentComponentComponent //this component gets loaded when in router-link when home page is loaded.
  }
];
```

The `nav` has couple of menu items, an inline login form (username/password) as well as a signup link.  The router file has rules to load new components in `content` area.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light ">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1" aria-controls="navbar1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">CodingJedi</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbar1">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="widgets.html">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><!-- Navbar Form -->
        <form class="form-inline" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="signInUser()" novalidate>
          <label for="username" class="control-label required sr-only">Username</label>
          <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" formControlName="userName" [ngClass]="validateField('userName')" required>
          <app-show-errors [control]="loginForm.controls.userName"></app-show-errors>
          <label for="password" class="control-label required sr-only">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" formControlName="password" [ngClass]="validateField('password')" required>
          <app-show-errors [control]="loginForm.controls.password"></app-show-errors>

            <button type="submit" id="login-button" class="btn content-div__button--blue btn-sm">Sign In</button>

        </form>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink='signup'>Sign Up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

On clicking the signup link, a sign up form gets loaded.

```
<div class="div__signup"> 
  <div class="content_div--white">

    <form class="signup-form form-group" [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="addUser()" novalidate>
      <label for="firstname" class="control-label required">First Name</label>

      <input id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" [ngClass]="validateField('firstName')" required>
      <app-show-errors [control]="signupForm.controls.firstName"></app-show-errors>

      <label for="lastname" class="control-label required">Last Name</label>
      <input id="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lastName" [ngClass]="validateField('lastName')" required>
      <app-show-errors [control]="signupForm.controls.lastName"></app-show-errors>

      <label for="email" class="control-label required"> Email</label>
      <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" [ngClass]="validateField('email')" required>
      <app-show-errors [control]="signupForm.controls.email"></app-show-errors>

      <label for="password" class="control-label required">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" [ngClass]="validateField('password')" required>
      <app-show-errors [control]="signupForm.controls.password"></app-show-errors>

      <label for="verify-password" class="control-label required">Verify Password</label>
      <input id="verify-password" type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="confirmPassword" [ngClass]="validateField('confirmPassword')" required>
      <app-show-errors [control]="signupForm.controls.confirmPassword"></app-show-errors>


      <button type="submit"  id="signup-button" class="content-div__button--blue"> Sign Up! </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in angular but in my css. The SignupComponent's css was wrong. I had given it absolute position (position:absolute, top:0, left:0) which made it cover the entire page. So when I thought that I am clicking nav, I was actually clicking inside SignupComponent

Answer (score 0):

I think it's that your outlet is in a child component, not in AppComponent, ie. the component handling the root route. Should work if you replace app-content-component with router-outlet.

If you really badly want to have the rest of your layout in a content-component and a minimal AppComponent, you might get away with this in AppComponent (disclaimer: haven't tried):

```
<app-content-component><router-outlet></router-outlet><app-content-component>
```

and this in content-component:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Also, not a bug (yet), but in your nav you should use absolute routerLinks like /signup, in case later you may have routes with child routes.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about `ng-content` so your answer was helpful. Also thanks for the tip on router links. Turns out the problem wasn't Angular related. The `SignupComponent`'s css was wrong. I had given it absolute position (`position:absolute, top:0, left:0`) which made it cover the entire page. So when I thought that I am clicking `nav`, I was actually clicking inside `SignupComponent`.

Comment: BTW, I didn't use I didnt use `ng-content` and am sticking to my original design. From your experience, is it better that I use `<app-content-component><router-outlet></router-outlet></app-content-component>`? I need `app-content-component` as the layout of my app is decided by a `css-grid`. It is easy for me to specify position within the grid using `content-component`, else I'll have to specify it in all the components which I want to use within the `app-content-component`

Comment: Ah ok, np. Glad you found it. I guess it doesn't matter much. It just looks more clear to me when router outlet isn't hidden in a child. Looked wrong enough to make me think that was the problem. :) Minor detail and personal pref in the end.